# How can I increase the spacing between options for awesomeRadio in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app in shiny and the text overlaps the selectors, so I can't increase the space between them.

My sample code:

```r
div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 1200px;",
    awesomeRadio(
        inputId = "var_mapa",
        label = "País a escoger", 
        choices = c("Todos los países", opciones$PAÍS),
        inline = FALSE, 
        status = "success"
    )
)
```

but it doesn't work, the app looks like this:

[image]

Is there another way to separate the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine by using `inline = TRUE` without any additional CSS. If the example below doesn't work as expected, try updating `shiny` and `shinyWidgets` packages.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    awesomeRadio(
      inputId = "id2", label = "Pais a escoger:",
      choices = c("Todos los paises", "Argentina", "Brasil", "Colombia", "Mexico"),
      inline = TRUE, status = "success"
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```